# App Store message in Japanese - what does it mean?

Tags: apple-store

[image]

That's the message that always keeps popping up when I'm trying to update my game. I don't really understand Japanese so I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: hmmm, not really a translation site it is. App recommendation for the same would have been a better Q.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Google Translate of the characters in the pop up message image:

[image]

The buttons キ ャ ン セ ル and 購 入 す る translate to Cancel and Purchase respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google translate's image feature in the app too. Allow camera access and import this screenshot.

[image]